# Multiple of 4 using XOR (Python)

Tags: python, xor

To check whether a number is a multiple of 4 or not without using +, -, * ,/ and % operators.

```
def multipleFour(n):
   if n == 1:
     return False
   XOR = 0
   for i in range(n):
        XOR = XOR ^ 1
   return XOR == n
multipleFour(20)
```

My answer returns False

Comment: Do you *need* to use xor, or are other bitwise operators acceptable? Typically, you'd test this with a mask (bitwise-and, `&`) and logical negation (`not`). `return not n & 0x3` (or `return n & 0x3 == 0`) would cover you, no xor needed (in C operator precedence you'd need to add parens, `return !(n & 0x3);`, but Python set the precedence for bitwise and boolean operators more naturally, so no parens needed).

Comment: So would `(x ^ 3) - x == 3`, but no subtraction... hmm..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mistaken in your **for loop** as well as **xor statement**. It should be like -

```
def multipleFour(n):
   if n == 1:
     return False
   XOR = 0
   for i in range(1, n+1):
        XOR = XOR ^ i
   return XOR == n
multipleFour(20)
```

i.e. your loop must run for i=1 to i=n and not i=0 to i=n-1. And it must be `xor = xor ^ i`

EDIT:

As pointed out in comments, **for i in range(1, n+1)** does not meet the condition of not using **+**, but by little modification, this thing can be solved as -

```
def multipleFour(n):
       if n == 1:
         return False
       XOR = n
       for i in range(1, n):
            XOR = XOR ^ i
       return XOR == n
    multipleFour(20)
```

Comment: That's pretty ingenious algorithm I did not know (and would be ridiculous to use in actual code). However... `i+1` seems to be cheating :P  Still +1 for teaching me a new thing, and answering the literal question better than any of the rest of us. :)

Comment: This uses `+` to compute the end of the `range`, so it violates the rules. But you could fix it by initializing `XOR` to `n` instead of `0`, then running the loop over `range(1, n)`.

Comment: Or because opportunities to use `reduce` (`functools.reduce` on Py3) are few and far between, and one-liners are fun, you could one-line the `XOR` computation as `reduce(operator.xor, range(1, n), n)` and then one-line the whole function to `def multipleFour(n): return n != 1 and n == reduce(operator.xor, range(1, n), n)`. :-D

Comment: @ShadowRanger Thanks for pointing out the mistake. All better now. Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

Your `XOR` starts with `0`, and the only operation you ever employ on it is `XOR ^ 1`; the result can only ever be `0` or `1`. Your code explicitly returns `False` on `1`, and can't return `True` on any larger number; it should only return `True` for `0`.

Meanwhile, it is very easy to check whether something is multiple of 4 "without using +, -, * ,/ and % operators.", using `AND` and `NOT`:

```
def multipleFour(n):
    return not(n & 3)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could check the binary and avoid xoring all integers from `0` to `n`:

```
0 0000
1 0001
2 0010
3 0011
4 0100  8 1000  12 1100
```

The binary signature of a multiple of four is `'00'`

```
def x_of_4(n):
    return bin(n)[-2:] == '00'
```

However, although converting to a string makes it easy to visualize and understand, it is not the best of ideas, and this method fails for `n = 0`.
**A better way** to do the same is to **bitwise-and-with 3** which will test the final two zeros of the binary representation (credits to @ShadowRanger in the comments:

```
def x_of_4(n):
    return not n & 3
```

Comment: Converting to a string is a kind of ridiculous way to do this, and it fails for `0`. Bitwise-and with `0x3` tests low bits directly (no type conversions) and works correctly for `0`.

Comment: Just for fun though, you could make it work by `strip`ing and ensuring the result is empty: `return not bin(n)[-2:].rstrip('b0')`

Comment: hehe, thank you. I knew there was a better way, I wanted to put it out there because it explains clearly how the underlying works, withou much complication. I was looking for the proper bitwise op when you posted your comment. I amended the answer to reflect your suggestion.